# How to display the number of threads in mono?

Tags: multithreading, mono

I tried the following code which works fine in the Windows CLR:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count
```

... resulting in something `> 0`.

However under Mono on OS X or Linux it always results in `0`

Is this a bug in Mono or do I need another approach because of platform differences?

Comment: I think this is related to how Linux/MacOS manages PIDs.

Comment: On Linux you could query the /proc file-system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going straight to the source, it appears that it's not exactly a bug, but is instead [completely unimplemented](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs#L687) (note the `[MonoTODO]` attribute on this method).

Your best course of action would be to open a bug against Mono on [Xamarin's bug tracker](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Class%20Libraries). It's probably not *terribly* hard to build this, and it seems like someone on the project may be ashamed enough that this isn't done that they'll fix it quickly.

If you need this to work in the meanwhile, I've got [a branch on github that implements a fix for this](https://github.com/sblom/mono/commit/ef6313d9c43e75db627984bf28206e099086de3b). I'll work with the Mono folks to see whether/how they want to integrate it.

**Update:** It has been pulled into the master branch of Mono.

Comment: Lesson learned, next time check the mono code :-) Thank you so much!

Comment: @Akira, just updated to add a link to a change that I've pushed to GitHub that enables your exact scenario. There's still a lot of unimplemented support around `ProcessThread`, but the `Count` should at least be correct.

Comment: Wow !!! Perfect!  I'll include your implementation into my environment and do some testing and give you a feedback.

Comment: hey sblom... you strike me as the kind of guy that studied at a high school for the maths and scientifics :)

Comment: Now when i played around with your solution i see there are a lot of threads showing up... the next question would be interesting to see what those threads are and in which state they are. and an empty correctly sized collection explains not too much. Hopefully you get some commitment from the mono folks. Looking forward to get any news!

Comment: @Akira, or perhaps you could take inspiration from my quick fix and make a contribution yourself? If you want my help getting started with this, I'm happy to do it!